# How to find out the Active window when printscreen was taken

Tags: windows, events, printscreen

I am creating a Bug filing client in Windows. The client activates when the user presses Windows + prnt screen . The latest captured image is pushed to the picturebox in the client [ windows form ] .

Is there any way to know which window was active when the print screen was taken. Can we dig to the event logs or any other way to find out the same?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is if your own app is taking the screen capture; then you can use `GetForegroundWindow` to capture the `HWND` of that window. If all you're seeing is the end-result of the capture after the default print screen action, you're out of luck.